# Titanium desktop build on Mac

Tags: python, macos, build, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to build a simple desktop application using the tibuild.py file. Here's the command I'm passing:

```
tibuild.py -v -n -o osx -t bundle -a . -s -d ~/tmp  ~/src/test
```

When I run this, I get an error saying:

```
File "/Users/seanoshea/eyefi/svn/manager/ti/build/titanium_desktop/sdk/app.py", line 4, in <module>
import effess
ImportError: No module named effess
```

I'm just using the stock Python version which comes with Mac OS X:

```
seanosheas-macbook-pro-2:sdk seanoshea$ python --version
Python 2.6.1
seanosheas-macbook-pro-2:sdk seanoshea$ which python
/usr/bin/python
seanosheas-macbook-pro-2:sdk seanoshea$
```

Do I have to manually install the Python module `effess`?

Comment: Turns out that I was missing a build artefact called kroll (https://github.com/appcelerator/kroll). effess.py is included in that packacge and you just need to pop it in the same directory as the tibuild.py file

Comment: Could you please provide your comment as an answer. Now others, when searching for old, unanswered questions will find your question again. You could, and probably should, even mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: Sure thing Anthon. Just added it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing a build artefact called [Kroll](https://github.com/appcelerator/kroll). `effess.py` is included in that package, and you just need to pop it in the same directory as the `tibuild.py` file